# How to navigate from Content Page to Shell in native forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In my xamarin forms native 3.x project, currently I am navigating from content page to content page using below code

```
Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment mainPage = new ContentPage().CreateSupportFragment(this);

        SupportFragmentManager
            .BeginTransaction()
            .Replace(Resource.Id.fragment_frame_layout, mainPage)
            .Commit();
```

Ref:- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-forms

But this is not working in case of navigation from content page to Shell (Xamarin Forms 4.0.0).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: yes,i also find this issue,and oddly enough, it works with the shell on ios